# The import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.OptimisticLocking cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, annotations, eclipselink

So I try to include these:

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.OptimisticLocking;
import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.OptimisticLockingType;
```

To use them like that:

```
@OptimisticLocking(type=OptimisticLockingType.VERSION_COLUMN)
```

That should be no problem, as in my classpath, in libraries, in Maven Dependencies, I have `Eclipselink_v2.6.0.jar`. So I checked in the `.jar` and it contains both `OptimisticLocking.class` and `OptimisticLockingType.class`.

But, after several cleans and restart of Eclipse, it still says that they cannot be resolved.

I noticed that `import org.eclipse.persistence.annotations.*;` actually works, but it doesn't provide any function/class. So Eclipse sees my `org.eclipse.persistence.annotations`, but it doesn't see that all the classes are in it.

Does anyone have an idea about the reason?

[image: eclipselink in the build path and OptimisticLocking.class is on the left, but there is still the error]